# Why would renaming HTML file fix an element positioning bug in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, position

I am writing a simple run and jump game using only a few hundred lines of vanilla JS, HTML and CSS. So far nothing complicated whatsoever.

My game was running okay, then without warning broke - suddenly the player element was offset down and to the right. Couldn't see any reason in code for this, and realized that just renaming the html file fixes the bug.
Also, opening the html file in firefox works perfectly with no bug (using original "chrome-buggy" name).

Any clue what could be the reason for this?

I don't care so much about making it work - since it already works with a new html file name. I'm interested in understanding what could have caused the issue.

Thank you

Comment: I doubt the name matters. I suspect something wrong got cached and renaming the file fetched it fresh.

Comment: @barmar so I renamed back to original name and the issue is there. Clearing "cached images and files did not fix it". I also ctrl + U to view page source and put that code in a different file - and there were no bugs.
Would i have to delete all my browsing history or something like that?

Comment: I can't think of any other effect that would be related to the filename.

Comment: Unless it contains code that check `window.location`.

Comment: @Barmar okay I cleared all browser data and it now works. Very inconvenient. I suppose this is the reason to use disable cache in dev tools. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Cleared all browser data. Clearing "cached images and files" was not enough, and reload/hard reload was not enough.

I will check "disable cache" under "network" in dev tools from now on to avoid this problem.